# symplectic change of variables

Tags: symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra, hamilton-jacobi-equation

I must prove that the change of variables $\Psi: (p,q)\rightarrow(r,\alpha)$
such that
$$q=\sqrt{2r}\cos(\alpha), \qquad p=\sqrt{2r}\sin(\alpha)$$
is symplectic.

What I know is:
$$\dot{q}=p, \qquad \dot{p}=\sin(q)$$

And so I deduce: $\ddot{q}=\sin(q)$, and $H(p,q)=\frac{p^2}{2}+\cos(q)$ is the Hamiltonian.

How can I prove that $\Psi$ is symplectic?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Jacobian matrix is
$$M=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial q}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial q}{\partial \alpha}\\\frac{\partial p}{\partial r}&\frac{\partial p}{\partial \alpha}\end{bmatrix}=\frac1{\sqrt{2r}}\begin{bmatrix}\cos\alpha&-2r\sin\alpha\\\sin\alpha&2r\cos\alpha\end{bmatrix}.$$
With $J=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{bmatrix}$, we have
$$M^TJM=J.$$
So by definition $M$ is a symplectic matrix and as the Jacobian matrix is symplectic, the change of variable $\Psi$ is symplectic.

Comment: I really like that! But I still have a question... I read that if I have a Hamiltonian system and I apply a symplectic change of coordinates, the new system is still hamiltonian. Is it true?

In my case I have $H(p,q)=\frac{p^2}{2}+cos(q)$, but doing the change I get: $$H(r,\alpha)=r sin^2(\alpha) + cos(\sqrt{2r}cos(\alpha))$$

And I'm not sure that it is Hamiltonian... Is it?

Comment: Sure, the Hamiltonian has symplectic symmetry. The change of variable $\Psi$ is standard for the harmonic oscillator, not for the sine potential that you have tried to used instead.

Comment: But for the harmonic oscillator I have $H(p,q)=\frac{1}{2}(p^2+q^2)$, and so $\dot{p}=-q$ but not $\dot{p}=sin(q)$.

Sorry for so many questions, but I still do not understand it... I suppose I must have $\dot{\alpha}=-\frac{dH(r, \alpha)}{dr}$ and $\dot{r}=\frac{dH(r,\alpha)}{d\alpha}$ in the new Hamiltonian $H(r,\alpha)$ isn't it?

How do I compute this new Hamiltonian? I thought it was $H(r,t)=H(\Psi(p,q))$

Thank you very much for your replies, it is really useful for me.

Comment: @Cherax. Yes the equation of motions are correct. The new Hamiltonian is the one you have given. I only doubt that it is easier to study in these new coordinates. Note that the Hamiltonian is the one of a pendulum in negative gravity.